# ¿Como controlar caracteres especiales al subir un plano?

Tags: php, regex

¿Se puede controlar que al subir un archivo plano, si una de las filas tiene caracteres como: `!@#$%&/(/()` el sistema me realice alguna validación?

Estoy intentando actualizar un registro y necesito hacer la validación antes mencionada. Estuve leyendo y encontré la función [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php), la quise aplicar de la siguiente manera y no me funciona:

```
$pattern =  '/(["!@#$%&\/()]")/';

if (preg_match($pattern,$valor)) {
    echo " se encontro caracteres especiales, validar plano ";
}
```

En la variable `$valor` se carga el campo grupo promoción el cual es el que deseo validar al momento de realizar la carga. Estoy utilizando PHP para hacer el formulario.

¿Por qué falla el código de arriba? ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? ¿Hay alguna otra forma de realizar la validación?

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta carece de la informacion necesaria para que alguno de nosotros pueda ayudarte. Por favor consulta la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorarla. Que cosa no funciona? porque no funciona? tira algun error? podrias agregar el codigo de lo que tenes hasta ahora para ayudarte?

Comment: @Norbey Hay una `"` de más al final de tu expresión. [`/(["!@#$%&\/()])/`](https://regex101.com/r/7tU8cL/2) obtiene el resultado que estás buscando.... Al igual que [`/["!@#$%&\/()]/`](https://regex101.com/r/7tU8cL/3)

Comment: Creo que después de darle formato al código, la pregunta se entiende y, como apunta Mariano, el error se puede encontrar con la información dentro de la pregunta en sí.

Comment: La pregunta quedó clara luego de la edición, pero estoy votando para cerrar como error tipográfico.

Comment: gracias @Mariano. Efectivamente el error radicaba en la "  que estaba de mas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una `"` de más al final de tu expresión. Funciona si se elimina:

```
/(["!@#$%&\/()])/
```

Y no son necesarios los paréntesis:

```
/["!@#$%&\/()]/
```